# Calendar Plays Wrong Sound

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, notifications, audio, calendar

I have set the sound in both `Personalize->Sound->Notification Sounds->Calendar` and `Calendar->Menu->Settings->Select Notification` to the same sound, but Calendar refuses to play the correct sound. It always plays some chime-sounding thing that doesn't get my attention at all. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What phone do you have?

Comment: I have an HTC One X.

Comment: Can you identify the sound? (Is it one of the other notification sounds in the list?) Is it the Google Calendar or is it some custom jobbie from HTC, or is it something else?

Comment: The sound is "Daybook." I searched for a file named "Day*" but didn't find anything. It's available for notifications and ringtones. Perhaps it's hard-coded?

Comment: If you have a "Calendar Event..." app, the settings in there can override other settings.

Answer (score 0):

For a quite comparable reason (missing appointments as I missed the "alarm"), but with a different cause (alarm didn't repeat until it got my attention), I've found two different solutions. Both are involving a third-party paid app, but there might be free alternatives as well – so let me use my solutions as examples first:

- At first, I used [Calendar Event Reminder](http://www.appbrain.com/app/de.foobarsoft.calendareventreminder). Here you can define per calendar what sound to use, and how often to repeat alarms until dismissed. You also can "snooze" an alarm to "buzz you later".
- Finally, I've switched to a different calendar altogether: [Business Calendar Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/mikado.bizcalpro) (which has a [free test version](http://www.appbrain.com/app/netgenius.bizcal) to try out first). Same principle as described above concerning repeating buzzes and snoozes, and of course you can select your sound.

What both solutions have in common is using an independent alarm system. So both recommend switching the notifications off in your default calendar, and only using the "new alarm system". Both variants worked perfectly for me, so I can really recommend them (depending on your requirements, chose what better fits you).

As for alternatives, you might wish to take a look at my lists on [Calender-Alarm-Fixes](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_alarmfixes) (alternatives to CER), or check whether another [calendar app](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_general) comes with its own alarm system (I vaguely remember there was at least one more).